# Data Scraping for Pagination of the Products to get all products details

Tags: web-scraping, lxml

I want to scrape all the product data for the 'Cushion cover' category having URL = 'https://www.noon.com/uae-en/home-and-kitchen/home-decor/slipcovers/cushion-cover/'
I analysed the data is in the script tag ,but how to get the data from all the pages. I required the URL's of all the Products from all the pages and the data is also in API for different pages API= 'https://www.noon.com/_next/data/B60DhzfamQWEpEl9Q8ajE/uae-en/home-and-kitchen/home-decor/slipcovers/cushion-cover.json?limit=50&page=2&sort%5Bby%5D=popularity&sort%5Bdir%5D=desc&catalog=home-and-kitchen&catalog=home-decor&catalog=slipcovers&catalog=cushion-cover'
if we goes on changing the page num in the above link we have the data for the respective pages but  how to get that data from different pages
Please suggest for this.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
from lxml import html

headers ={'authority': 'www.noon.com',
      'accept' : 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
      }
 produrl = 'https://www.noon.com/uae-en/home-and-kitchen/home-decor/slipcovers/cushion-cover/'
 prodresp = requests.get(produrl, headers = headers, timeout =30)
 prodResphtml = html.fromstring(prodresp.text)
 print(prodresp)


 partjson = prodResphtml.xpath('//script[@id= "__NEXT_DATA__"]/text()')
 partjson = partjson[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are about to reach your goal. You can make the next pages meaning pagination using `for loop and range function` to pull all the pages as we know that total page numbers are 192 that's why I've made the pagination this robust way. So to get all the products `url` (or any data item) from all of the pages, you can follow the next example.

**Script:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from lxml import html

headers ={
      'authority': 'www.noon.com',
      'accept' :'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
      }
produrl = 'https://www.noon.com/uae-en/home-and-kitchen/home-decor/slipcovers/cushion-cover/?limit=50&page={page}&sort[by]=popularity&sort[dir]=desc'
data=[]
for page in range(0,192):
    prodresp = requests.get(produrl.format(page=page), headers = headers, timeout =30)
    prodResphtml = html.fromstring(prodresp.text)
    #print(prodresp)

    partjson = prodResphtml.xpath('//script[@id= "__NEXT_DATA__"]/text()')
    #partjson = partjson[0]
    partjson = json.loads(partjson[0])
    #print(partjson)

    # with open('data.json','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    #     f.write(partjson)

    for item in partjson['props']['pageProps']['props']['catalog']['hits']:
        link='https://www.noon.com/'+item['url']
        data.append(link)

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['URL'])
#df.to_csv('product.csv',index=False)#to save data into your system
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                     URL
0     https://www.noon.com/graphic-geometric-pattern...
1     https://www.noon.com/classic-nordic-decorative...
2     https://www.noon.com/embroidered-iconic-medusa...
3     https://www.noon.com/geometric-marble-texture-...
4     https://www.noon.com/traditional-damask-motif-...
...                                                 ...
9594  https://www.noon.com/geometric-printed-cushion...
9595  https://www.noon.com/chinese-style-art-printed...
9596  https://www.noon.com/chinese-style-art-printed...
9597  https://www.noon.com/chinese-style-art-printed...
9598  https://www.noon.com/chinese-style-art-printed...

[9599 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Can we have the dynamic range for pages if the range changes accordingly ?

Comment: Please suggest for that

Comment: And if we try to hit the url it's not working .It requires more parameters in it

Comment: As we  know the total pages, so this is the robust way to make pagination and  two time faster and you can increase od decrease page numbers with no times from range. All links working fine when  i  hit to oepn in browser.  Please uncomment to_csv portion and it will store  data into your local and from there you can open any url oo the  browser to test. I've solved so  many such types of problem

Comment: But I want to scrape for different categories so want to have the dyanamic page number means can we get logically the last page num in the range dyanamically

Comment: Actually, this page number is also sent dynamically. I 've counted the page number from dynamice  response. They have said there total pages ,per page items and total count. Actually,you didn't see the dynamic  count like me or not understanding about dynamic response. I have made the pagination on the basis of dynamic response. If page number change , then whole process will also be changed

Comment: @F.Hogue : Can you please suggest for this question      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72513224/data-scraping-of-the-numbers-and-details-from-the-website

Answer (score 0):

I used re lib. In other word, I used regex it is much better to scrape any page use JavaScript

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
from lxml import html
import re
headers ={
    'authority': 'www.noon.com',
    'accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
      }
url = "https://www.noon.com/uae-en/home-and-kitchen/home-decor/slipcovers/cushion-cover/"
prodresp = requests.get(url, headers = headers, timeout =30)
jsonpage = re.findall(r'type="application/json">(.*?)</script>', prodresp.text)
jsonpage = json.loads(jsonpage[0])
```