# Data Scraping of the Numbers and details from the website

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I want to scrape the contact numbers from the website with the respective details of the Courier Services. I am not able to scrape the Contact numbers and other details like name address and rating from all the Courier services. I analyzed the data is in the script tag. Please suggest a fix for this

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
from lxml import html
import re
headers ={'authority': 'www.justdial.com',
      'accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9 ',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
      'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" }


produrl = 'https://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Courier-Services-in-Mumbai-Bazar-Nalasopara-East/nct-10142628'
prodresp = requests.get(produrl, headers=headers, timeout=30)
prodResphtml = html.fromstring(prodresp.text)
partjson = prodResphtml.xpath('/html/head/script[9]/text()')
print(partjson)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's data are coming with ajax api call from there;

`https://www.justdial.com/api/india_api_write/20march2020/searchziva.php?city=Mumbai&area=Mumbai-Bazar-Nalasopara-East&lat=&long=&darea_flg=0&case=spcall&stype=category_list&search=Courier-Services&national_catid=10142628&nextdocid=&attribute_values=&basedon=&sortby=&nearme=0&max=100&pg_no=1`

Comment: But how to get the data from this API not getting , I want to scrape the contact details